# Why doesn’t effective mass (like the internal mass of an electron) have any interactions with the stress-energy tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass

I’ve read in a lot of places that what differentiates effective masses from “real” masses is that effective mass is inertial only and that it has no effect on the stress energy tensor.

I’m a layman and this confuses me. from what little I understand, I thought that there was an equivalence between inertial and gravitational mass, and that someone on a very fast moving cylinder wouldn’t be able to tell if he was on a planet or not.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Can you cite one or two places where you read this? The sources might have been using some words a bit loosely, and seeing the context can help us diagnose that.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "effective mass" the mass appearing in the $E=mc^2$, the relativistic mass , it is not an inertial mass, i.e. a mass characterizing a given particle for all inertial frames  because relativistic mass  depends on the velocity of the particle.

> [Inertial mass](https://www.britannica.com/science/inertial-mass) is a mass parameter giving the inertial resistance to acceleration of the body when responding to all types of force. *Gravitational mass* is determined by the strength of the gravitational force experienced by the body when in the gravitational field $g$ .

The equivalence principle is between these two definitions.

It is true that relativistic mass, which increases with velocity acts *like an inertial mass* to a force applied, within a particular inertial frame. For example in order to accelerate further the fuel necessary for future space travels. But special relativity, which models this mass, is included in General Relativity equations which involve the stress-energy tensor.

The [stress energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) does not interact with anything, it is a mathematical description of all the energy and momentum  in the system studied, and its form depends on the framework, whether classical, special relativity, general relativity.

You state:

> I thought that there was an equivalence between inertial and gravitational mass, and that someone on a very fast moving cylinder wouldn’t be able to tell if he was on a planet or not.

This is in the classical mechanics frame, where there is no relativistic mass defined.

> What am I getting wrong?

You are mixing up the classical mechanics framework, the special relativity framework  and the general relativity framework.

If one does not keep consistently within a framework, paradoxes appear.

Also to really understand such concepts one has to study the physics involved.